# Connectivity between R and Hive

Tags: r, hive

I am trying to establish a connection between RStudio (on my machine) and Hive (which is setup on a different server).  Here's my R code:

```
install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)
require(RJDBC)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", 
       classPath = list.files("C:/Users/37/Downloads/hive-jdbc-0.10.0.jar",
       pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
       identifier.quote="'")
```

Here is the error I get while executing the above commands:

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhivejdbc0100jar.htm)) : class not found
>   conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://65.11.23.453:10000/default", "admin", "admin")

I downloaded the jar files from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhivejdbc0100jar.htm) and placed them in the **CLASSPATH**.  Please advise if am doing anything wrong and how I could get this to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cloudera, check version and download jars for that.
Example
CDH 5.9.1
hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.1.jar
hive-jdbc-1.1.1-standalone.jar

copy the jars into a folder into R host and execute:

```
 library("DBI")

 library("rJava")

 library("RJDBC")

#init of the classpath (works with hadoop 2.6 on CDH 5.4 installation)
cp = c("/home/youruser/rlibs/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.1.jar", "/home/youruser/rlibs/hive-jdbc-1.1.1-standalone.jar")
.jinit(classpath=cp)

#initialisation de la connexion
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", /home/youruser/rlibs/hive-jdbc-1.1.1-standalone.jar", identifier.quote="`")

conn <- dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:hive2://HiveServerHostInYourCluster:10000/default;", "YourUserHive", "xxxx")

#working with the connexion
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
show_databases
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this sample code and it worked for me:

```
library(RJDBC)

#Load Hive JDBC driver
hivedrv <- JDBC("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
                c(list.files("/home/amar/hadoop/hadoop",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
                  list.files("/home/amar/hadoop/hive/lib",pattern="jar$",full.names=T)))

#Connect to Hive service
hivecon <- dbConnect(hivedrv, "jdbc:hive://ip:port/default")
query = "select * from mytable LIMIT 10"
hres <- dbGetQuery(hivecon, query)
```

Comment: Please could let me know where exactly can i get all the jar files required for hive connectivity ?

Comment: the first statement works now, but getting error in db connect statement > conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive://54.77.162.203:10000/default")
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException

Comment: hive is installed on a different server, i do not have it on my machine. I have R on my machine and am trying to connect to the hive which is hosted on a different server.

Comment: That is ok, you just need the jar files. there is some particular jar file you are missing which is giving this class not found exception. Also are you loading library(RJDBC) before trying to create the connection ?

Comment: This is what i do, install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)
library(RJDBC)drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
            classPath = list.files("C:/Users/370398/Downloads/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
            identifier.quote="'")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive://54.77.162.203:10000/default"). Would you be able to share the jar files somehow ? or could share a path from where i can take them ?

Comment: copy the jar files from the lib folder of serve where hive is installed. Or either download hive in your machine and copy jars from there

Comment: I have tried these options, i just dont seem to get access to the server where Hive is present, not i can install it on mine due to restricted permissions. Can i check if there is any other way at all please ?

Comment: out of box, but can you try pinging that server and see you have access to that server at that specific port ?

Comment: I managed to download files and now have all jar files i think. But still getting the below error, conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive://54.77.162.203:10000/default")
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol.getScheme()Ljava/lang/Class; please could you help ?

Comment: Hi, R is hung after the below messages(i guess these are only warnings), but is R establishing a connection ? > conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive://54.77.162.203:10000/default")
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/370398/Downloads/hive-0.12.0-bin.tar/hive-0.12.0-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/370398/Downloads/hive-0.12.0.tar/hive-0.12.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Comment: it just says that there are multiple jars files for SLF4j. Try removing one of them and try again...this should go away

Comment: Have done that and have got rid of the warnings, however R seems hung, does this mean it is establishing connectivity with hive ?

Comment: ideally it shouldn't hang if it is making a connection..just check if you have to that server and port

Comment: Hi - have tried all the below so far - but no luck !!! I am able to establish connectivity using RODBC and respective driver setup, but RJDBC connectivity doesnt work. > drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",             
+             classPath = c(list.files("D:/Mothi_16-07-14/hive_Jar_Files/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
+                           list.files("D:/Mothi_16-07-14/hadoop_Jar_Files/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T)))
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://54.77.162.203:10000/default","","")

Comment: Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid URL: jdbc:hive2://54.77.162.203:10000/default

Comment: If i use driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" then am getting Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars...Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me earlier when I was trying to use RJDBC to connect to Cassandra, it was solved by putting the Cassandra JDBC dependencies in your JAVA ClassPath.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272577/935940):

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this post there are a couple things you can try to fix the problem:

1.) reinstall `rJava` from source `install.packages("rJava","http://rforge.net/",type="source")`

2.) Initiate java debugger for loading and try to connect again
`.jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L)`

3.) I've had to use both `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = /Path/to/java)` before and utilize `dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')` to find the right jvm library.

4.) As stated [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite), you can also create a link between the the `libjvm.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib`

`sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

If all of these fail, a uninstall and install of R has also worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me so far.

1) First check if the hive service is running, if not restart it.

```
sudo service hive-server2 status
sudo service hive-server2 restart
```

2) install rJava and RJDBCin R.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

options(java.parameters = '-Xmx8g')
hadoop_jar_dirs <- c('/usr/lib/hadoop/lib',
                     '/usr/lib/hadoop',
                     '/usr/lib/hive/lib')
clpath <- c()
for (d in hadoop_jar_dirs) {
  clpath <- c(clpath, list.files(d, pattern = 'jar', full.names = TRUE))
}
.jinit(classpath = clpath)
.jaddClassPath(clpath)

hive_jdbc_jar <- '/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar'
hive_driver <- 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver'
hive_url <- 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default'
drv <- JDBC(hive_driver, hive_jdbc_jar)
conn <- dbConnect(drv, hive_url)
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")

show_databases
```

Make sure to give correct path to ***hadoop_jar_dirs, hive_jdbc_jar and hive_driver.***

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package for dealing with this (and kerberos):

```
devtools::install_github('nfultz/hiveuberjar')

require(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(hiveuberjar::HiveUber(), url="jdbc://host:port/schema")
dbListTables(con)
dbGetQuery(con, "Select count(*) from nfultz.iris limit 10")
```