# How to add additional database options to "Connect to Existing Data Sources" pane in RStudio

Tags: r, database, rstudio

I am following the instructions for how to [create new database connections in RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010915687-Using-RStudio-Connections). I can open the pane "Connect to Existing Data Sources" but how do I add more database options to this list (e.g., my company uses Vertica and Hive)?

I can connect to other databases in R and RStudio code chunks using DBI, but these databases are not listed in the "Connect to Existing Data Sources" pane. How do I add them to this pane?

Comment: You can add Vertica using `RODBC` and `RJDBC` package.[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276487/connectivity-between-r-and-hive) and [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285503/connect-r-and-vertica-using-rodbc)

Comment: @NirbhaySingh I can connect to Vertica via DBI::dbConnect() within an Rmd chunk, but I cannot get Vertica or Hive to display in the list under "Connect to Existing Data Sources". If I could establish a connection via this GUI it would allow me to use more of RStudio's database functionality in the panes, such as seeing all the tables and schemas in drop downs.